# What does this number mean? in sqldbx connection with remote database

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Please tell me what is this number that is displayed on the title bar of sqldbx every time when i connect to my database this changed with connection

But it shows `(58)` every time i connect to local database every time.

Comment: Perhaps it's your SPID? Try `SELECT @@SPID` in a query window.

Comment: then why it is every time 58 for local database

Comment: I consistently get 53 on my local database, because I'm the only one using it I end up being the 53rd SPID over and over again.

Comment: the same with me i am getting 58 consistently with my local database but changes when i connect to remote db

Comment: Because other people have connected before you? So they're 53, 54, 55, 56, ... 77 and you're SPID 78.

Comment: in local only i am connected to my db

Comment: SQL Server has its own processes that run and use up SPIDs. Especially <= 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is SPID

@@SPID can be used to identify the current user process in the output of sp_who.

Answer (score 0):

Its spid. This id controlled by server for connections chech it by sp_who

Comment: oh thanks but I think something same i've searched but thanks